# Change file association (NOT command I)

Tags: finder, high-sierra, plist

I changed the file association for my .dvdmedia files on my Mac to point at Blu-ray Player Pro. As it turns out this was a mistake as it turned all the .dvdmedia files into plain directories. Google has shown me the usual cmd-I solution (which doesn't work because what were bundles are being viewed as directories because of the file association on .dvdmedia) and some outdated advice to try duti which unfortunately doesn't compile on High Sierra (and might not work at all, who knows?). Presumably there's some way to fix this by editing a plist somewhere, but I've not found it yet. I did find that logging in as a different user showed the files correctly. Any thoughts on how to undo my gross mistake?

I've tried editing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` in XCode and discovered that the file association gets reset as below:
[image: Screen shot of plist editing in XCode]

The association with public.iso-image is what I would like to have for dvdmedia.

**Update**: I was able to change the association in the .plist file and have it stick by logging out and back in again, but the .dvdmedia files still show as directories rather than single files. There must be something more than this one plist that is causing .dvdmedia files to be incorrectly displayed... I really don't want to have to re-rip the DVDs that I've put on my hard drive if I can avoid it.

**Update 2**: I tried moving `~/Library/Preferences` to `Preferences.old` and logging out/back in. STILL have folders instead of bundles.

Comment: Please explain "which doesn't work because what were bundles are being viewed as directories because of the file association on .dvdmedia) and some outdated advice to try duti which unfortunately doesn't compile on High Sierra (and might not work at all, who knows?"

Comment: The .dvdmedia files which are normally bundles in Finder now appear as directories rather than single files so I can't cmd-I them to change the association.

Comment: duti does not support OS X beyond 10.10 in the most recent version wtih a configure script (the latest version lacks the script so I can't even try to compile it).

Comment: What application do you want it to open in?

Comment: Also can you add a screen shot of the CMD - i window of one of the files/folders?

Comment: Can you restore these files from a Time Machine or other backup?

Comment: Time machine doesn't work because it's a global file association. If I knew where in the library the association is being stored I could maybe fix it. Logging in as a different user, incidentally, shows the .dvdmedia files as bundles and not directories.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.DS_Store` files in the affected directories? You may need to rebuild a cache (maybe the Dock or Kernel caches?). However, it's likely not a system-wide change since logging in as a different user shows the correct view. As such, you may be better off deleting the .plist file and restarting. This will hopefully reassociate the files.